# Catch NULL and ' ' if returned out SQL DB

Tags: android, sql, null

To catch an empty field out of my DB I use following code:

```
int score;
            if (c.isNull(11)) {
                score = 100;
            } else {
                score = c.getInt(11);
            }
            q.setScore(score);
```

But, it seems now that when I accidently have highlighted a cell in SQL Lite browser in the past, and export it (even left empty) it doesn't appear as `NULL` anymore, but as `''`
. I tried `c.getInt(11) = ''`but then again, this is not working...

Any ideas on how I could catch the `''` as well?

Comment: You might also alter the query itself:  `SELECT NULLIF(mycol, '') ...` or even `SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(mycol, ''), 100)...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `getInt()`, `null` and "empty" SQL values becomes `0` in Java (since `null` is not a valid Integer value), so use:

```
if(c.getInt(11) == 0)
```

If this creates a logic problem since `0` might mean somthing else in your context, you can run an UPDATE command on your table to change every `''` value to `-1` in this particular column.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution indeed, it is rather strange that the SQL browser makes '' of it instead of leaving it NULL. Anyway, thanks, I think I will update everything to -1 and use int score;
            if (c.getInt(11) = -1) {
                score = 100;
            } else {
                score = c.getInt(11);
            }
            q.setScore(score); That way the problem should be solved I think.

Comment: Glad I could help and I would find that `''` quirk frustrating too. It may just be a typo but remember to use `==` not `=` when testing equality in `if (c.getInt(11) == -1)`.

Comment: Yes indeed, just a typo :). Thanks for the help Sam!

Answer (score 0):

A column that returns `''` would result in `c.getInt` returning 0.